# Is there a bug in the cgmath Rust library?

Tags: math, matrix, rust, linear-algebra, quaternions

I'm making a ray tracer, and I have a function that does some math with `Matrix4`s. I've noticed that the outputs are wildly incorrect, and I'm just using the out-of-the-box `cgmath` functions.

```
    pub fn recalculate_view(self) {
        let mut view_lock = VIEW.lock().unwrap();
        *view_lock = Matrix4::look_to_rh(Point3::new(self.cam_pos.x, self.cam_pos.y, self.cam_pos.z), self.cam_pos + self.cam_dir, Vector3::new(0., 1., 0.));
        println!("view: {:?}",view_lock);
        if let Some(matrix) = view_lock.invert() {
            *INVERSE_VIEW.lock().unwrap() = matrix;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what to do... I'm using the correct functions, but the values aren't correct, even accounting for floating-point inaccuracy (according to the calculators I double-checked with).

The `recalculate_view` function takes in a `Camera` object (most notably the `cam_dir` and `cam_pos`) and edits the values of static `Lazy<Mutex<Matrix4<f32>>>`s such as `VIEW`. The issue possibly lies in the quaternion transforms I apply to the camera beforehand, though I'm not sure. I'll include that code snippet and [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/KGL8/RayTracingPaper/tree/working_snapshot/src) as well, just in case.

```
if input.mouse_held(1) == true {
            let_cursor_move = false;
            hide_cursor = true;
            
            if delta.x != 0.0 || delta.y != 0.0 {
                let pitch_delta = delta.y * 0.3;
                let yaw_delta = delta.x * 0.3;
    
                let rotation_pitch = Quaternion::from_axis_angle(right_direction,-Rad(pitch_delta));
                let rotation_yaw = Quaternion::from_axis_angle(Vector3::new(0.0,1.0,0.0),-Rad(yaw_delta));
    
                let q = quaternion_normalize(quaternion_cross(rotation_pitch, rotation_yaw));
                self.cam_dir = q.rotate_vector(self.cam_dir);
    
                moved = true;
            }
        }
```

For additional context, I'm following TheCherno's ray tracing series and am currently on [Episode 6](https://github.com/TheCherno/RayTracing/commit/9d87678b428f2957c860483d84850449245769c9)

Comment: It's not out of the question that there might be a bug in the library, but to establish that you would need to find a specific input for which you can say exactly what the output should be, and show how the observed output is different.

Comment: Don't ask "randomg people on the internet" whether you found a bug, file your findings over on the cgmath issue tracker, because if you _did_ find a bug, they'll want to know, and if you didn't find a bug, they're the authority on that. SO is your last resort when you've run out of obvious places for information.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the order or combination of transformations applied to the camera direction (self.cam_dir) in your mouse movement code. In the code snippet you provided, you're using quaternions to rotate the camera direction vector (self.cam_dir). However, the order in which you apply the rotations may be causing unexpected results. I think first you need to apply the yaw rotation and then the pitch rotation. This ensures that the yaw rotation is applied around the global up axis (0, 1, 0), while the pitch rotation is applied around the camera's right direction. Try this...

```
if input.mouse_held(1) {
let_cursor_move = false;
hide_cursor = true;

if delta.x != 0.0 || delta.y != 0.0 {
    let pitch_delta = delta.y * 0.3;
    let yaw_delta = delta.x * 0.3;

    let rotation_pitch = Quaternion::from_axis_angle(right_direction, -Rad(pitch_delta));
    let rotation_yaw = Quaternion::from_axis_angle(Vector3::new(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), -Rad(yaw_delta));

    let q = quaternion_normalize(rotation_yaw * rotation_pitch); // Adjusted order of quaternion multiplication
    self.cam_dir = q.rotate_vector(self.cam_dir);

    moved = true;
}
```

}